# Map Markers not being added to map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, closures

I am trying to use closure to have multiple map markers and none of the markers are being added to the map. I have searched for hours with no luck, no errors are caught by the console, and I can't see anything wrong with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is my code:

```
      var locations = [
      [53.471809, -2.242170, "content1", 'img1.jpg'],
      [53.466407, -2.234769, "content2", 'img2.jpg],
      [53.477134, -2.255313, "content3", 'img3.jpg'],
      [53.462775, -2.291624, "content4", 'img5.jpg']
      ];
      var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(53.47203,-2.2386741);

      function initialise() {

        var mapOptions={
        center: latLong,
        zoom: 16
    }
    var mapContainer=document.getElementById("mapArea");
    var map=new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOptions);



    function setMarkers(map,locations){

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
        {  

        var lat = locations[i][0];
        var long = locations[i][1];
        var add =  locations[i][2];
        var img = locations[i][3];

        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
              map: map, position: latlngset,icon:img  
                });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());


        var content = add;

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        marker.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        };
    })(marker,content,infowindow));  

      }
  }
  setMarkers();
}
window.addEventListener('load',initialise);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to call the `setMarkers` function.
2. You need the full path to the icon image.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cm7rvqbw/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  [53.471809, -2.242170, "content1", 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'],
  [53.466407, -2.234769, "content2", 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'],
  [53.477134, -2.255313, "content3", 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange.png'],
  [53.462775, -2.291624, "content4", 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png']
];
var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(53.47203, -2.2386741);

function initialise() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: latLong,
    zoom: 11
  }
  var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapArea");
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOptions);
  setMarkers(map, locations);


  function setMarkers(map, locations) {

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      var lat = locations[i][0];
      var long = locations[i][1];
      var add = locations[i][2];
      var img = locations[i][3];

      latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlngset,
        icon: img
      });
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());


      var content = add;

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      marker.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(content);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
      })(marker, content, infowindow));

    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', initialise);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapArea {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapArea"></div>
```

Comment: They are the full paths to the images, I have the images locally. I must have deleted calling the setMarkers function at some point, but it still doesn't work, now locations is being seen as undefined